# Phonegap XMLHttpRequest upload progress

Tags: android, cordova, upload, xmlhttprequest, progress

In my Phonegap 3.0.0 application I occasionally upload/download data.

As the upload migth sometimes reach up to couple of MB, I'd like to show to the user that progress is being made.

I wanted to accomplish this using xhr.upload "progress" event using code I found on the web

```
$.ajax({
  xhr: function()
  {
    var xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
    //Upload progress
    xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", function(evt){
      if (evt.lengthComputable) {
        var percentComplete = evt.loaded / evt.total;
        //Do something with upload progress
        console.log(percentComplete);
      }
    }, false);
    //Download progress
    xhr.addEventListener("progress", function(evt){
      if (evt.lengthComputable) {
        var percentComplete = evt.loaded / evt.total;
        //Do something with download progress
        console.log(percentComplete);
      }
    }, false);
    return xhr;
  },
  type: 'POST',
  url: "/",
  data: {},
  success: function(data){
    //Do something success-ish
  }
});
```

No event on upload progress is however received when I test my app on Android 4.1.2 [S3 mini] and 2.3.4 [Xperia].

I should probably also mention that the upload is done cross-platform. and jQuery version is 2.0.3

Am I doing something wrong, or the built-in Android browser simply does not support this? Is there a way I could get this working?

Thanx for help